# Error opening a ViewController

Tags: ios, crash, viewcontroller

I am getting this error code when I am Going to a TableViewController

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<GuestlistViewControler 0xbc458e0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key GueslistViewControler.'
```

However, it was already working before

So now when I am opening the App, everything is working, no Warning and No error. But when I am going in my TabBar to this Page, The whole App Freeze and I get the error Above.

.m

```
//
//  GuestlistViewControler.m
//  Club La Boom
//
//  Created by Kevin Archambault on 2014-04-21.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Club La Boom. All rights reserved.
//

#import "GuestlistViewControler.h"

@implementation GuestlistViewControler

-(IBAction)addData:(id)sender{

    NSString *name = self.NameText.text;
    NSString *invite = self.InviteText.text;
    NSString *email = self.EmailText.text;
    NSString *phone = self.CellText.text;
    NSString *date = self.DateText.text;

    NSString *rawStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&invite=%@&&email=%@&phone=%@&date=%@", name,
                        invite,
                        email,
                        phone,
                        date];

    NSData *data = [rawStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.clublaboom.com/guestlist_iphone.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:data];
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    NSString *responseString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseData bytes]];
    NSLog(@"%@", responseString);

    NSString *success = @"success";
    [success dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)responseString.length);
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)success.length);



    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Félicitation" message:@"Votre guestlist à été enregistré!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertsuccess show];

}



@end
```

.h

```
//
//  GuestlistViewControler.h
//  Club La Boom
//
//  Created by Kevin Archambault on 2014-04-21.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Club La Boom. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>


@interface GuestlistViewControler :
UITableViewController {
    UITextField *_NameText;
    UITextField *_InviteText;
    UITextField *_EmailText;
    UITextField *_CellText;
    UITextField *_DateText;
    UIButton *_SubmitButton;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewController *GuestlistViewControler;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField * NameText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField * InviteText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField * EmailText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField * CellText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField * DateText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton * SubmitButton;




@end
```

Comment: Please search on the error. This has been covered over and over before.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NSUnknownKeyException+this+class+is+not+key+value+coding-compliant+for+the+key

Comment: Is there a reason why you're declaring your textfield properties twice?

Comment: Check spelling of "GueslistViewControler".  There's a missing 't' that may be causing trouble.

Answer (score -1):

Somewhere in you code you are misspelling `GuestlistViewControler`. In Xcode on the left select the search button:

[image]

Type GueslistViewControler and press enter. Replace the `GueslistViewControler` with `GuestlistViewControler`.